# How to return "0" sales for a kind of subtexture from a left join of results that is null

Tags: sql, derby

DBMS: Derby

Language: Java

The outer query get the results off the inner query in which
it gets the sales of a kind of subtexture within a certain date
but sometimes there are no order details for a certain kind of 
subtexture. So there is nothing to join, I'd like to see a "0"
for this kind of situation. Sorry for the bad naming and indentation.
Thanks
Jack

```
SELECT s1.TextureName AS TYPE,
       T.month AS MONTH,
       NULLIF(sum(S.Sales),0) AS NS,
       NULLIF(T.Total,0) AS total,
       NULLIF(NULLIF(cast(S.Sales AS Float),0.0) / NULLIF(Cast(T.Total AS float),0.0) * 100.0,0.0) AS percent
FROM subtexture s1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT s.SubTextureID,
          sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales,
          MONTH(o.PURCHASEDATETIME) AS MONTH
   FROM subtexture s
   LEFT JOIN products p ON (s.SubTextureID = p.SubTextureID)
   LEFT JOIN order_details od ON (p.ProductCode = od.ProductCode)
   LEFT JOIN orders o ON (od.OrderCode = o.OrderCode)
   WHERE TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' || TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) = '2013-11'
   GROUP BY s.SubTextureID,
            MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime)) AS S ON (S.SubTextureID = s1.SubTextureID) ,
  (SELECT sum(od.NetSales) AS Total,
          MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS MONTH
   FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
   WHERE TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' ||TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) = '2013-11'
   GROUP BY MONTH(o.PURCHASEDATETIME)) AS T
WHERE T.MONTH = S.MONTH
GROUP BY s1.TextureName,
         T.Total,
         T.MONTH,
         S.Sales
```

Comment: Simplify your question and post only relevant parts of the query. Think of a much simpler example that also illustrates your problem.

Comment: Why did you use the Java tag? I cant see any Java related part in the question.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to cancel the Java tag

Comment: ok. I'm about to write an answer, but your SQL is way more complicated, then I first thought. Can you explain a bit more, what the SQL does and why you join the `order` twice and the `subtexture` twice? And what you try to achieve with the `nullif`. I think the mistake is in the `nullif`which should be `coalsesce`, but I also believe that you have other problems in the SQL, too.

Comment: And while I'm here :-) Is it right to say, that a subtexture always has a product (no need for outer join)? A product does not always have orders (Need for outer join)? A order always has at least one order_detail (no need for outer join) ?

Comment: Yes, a subtexture always has a product. I write a orders join twice, if we are talking about the second one, because I need to calculate the sum of all sales and calculate the percentage of the sales (sales of subtexuture over the total sales of all subtextures), otherwise, I need to join the orders table because the date of purchase is included only in the orders table

Comment: Hello jboi, Which one are we talking about on the colasescing?

Comment: still thinking about the answer. I more or less rewrite the query, as I also think that `Total` and `Sales`will have the same values. Give me one more minute (maybe two :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping. And like you said, probably I don't need the first left join. Great people here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there're some issues with the code. Unfortunately I dont have tables and test data. So keep in mind, that I wrote the result more or less out of my head. Test carefully.

To make it easier to read, I seperated the code into two steps. The first step gets the sum of sales and the second step calculates the total sales over all textures and builds the percentage. For your test, copy the first code two times into the second code, replacing the two occurences of `SALES_ONE_TEXTURE`. I just dont want to flood the answer more then necessary.

Here's the first part for sum of sales for one texture (and month and year)

```
-- Use this as subselect. And you're right: you need it twice
(   select  s.TextureName, s.SubTextureId, o.year, o.month, sum(COALESCE(d.NetSales, 0)) NetSales
    from    (select SubTextureId, TextureName from subtexture) as s
    join
            (select SubTextureId, ProductCode from products) as p
        on  (p.SubTextureId = s.SubTextureId)
    left outer join
            (select ProductCode, OrderCode, NetSales from order_details) as d
        on  (d.ProductCode = p.ProductCode)
    join
            (   select  YEAR(o.PurchaseDateTime) year,
                        MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime) month,
                        OrderCode
                from    orders
                where   o.PurchaseDateTime between '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and '2013-11-30 23:59:59' -- make use of an index if one exists
            ) as o
        on  (o.orderCode = d.orderCode)
    group by 1,2,3,4
)   as SALES_ONE_TEXTURE;
```

And here the outer code to bring the numbers together:

```
-- The outer query
select  O.TextureName,
        A.year, A.month,
        A.NetSales, O.NetSales,
        cast(O.NetSales as float) / cast(A.NetSales as float) * 100.0 as percent
from    SALES_ONE_TEXTURE O -- replace here
join
        (   select  year, month, sum(NetSales) as NetSales
            from    SALES_ONE_TEXTURE -- replace here
            group by 1, 2 
        ) as SALES_ALL_TEXTURES A
    on  (A.year = O.year and A.month = O.month)
```

Remarks

- `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value is often used to replace a null value with a default value. `NULLIF`does the opposite: Replace a value with null.
- Replacing a null that comes from an outer join does not work in all dialects on all RDBMS. You have to try if it works here. If not, you need to put the whole query in a subselect and do the `coalesce` replacement in the outer select
- I passed always year and month thru, where you passed the month. A month repeats every year, so only the combination is unique. I also changed the way to get the month. My way can make use of an index if one exists.

Comment: Thanks jboi, It's late night here. I need to test these tomorrow, I trust you, you are all experts in here. Let me report back tomorrow. Have fun.

Comment: I have followed your hints, But one thing is that I can't have a subtexture that has zero number of sales to be displayed. Say SubTexture A has sales of 1000, type b has 2000 and type c has 0, type c has never come up

Comment: That's one of the things I wasn't sure about. If subtexture has products but no orders (and therefore no order_details) you might need to join orders with an outer join: So, try and replace in the first part the `join` just before ordery are joined with `left outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NULLIF(sum(S.Sales),0) AS NS,
...
NULLIF(NULLIF(cast(S.Sales AS Float),0.0) / NULLIF(Cast(T.Total AS float),0.0) * 100.0,0.0) AS percent
```

This is never going to work. Simplifying it a bit, you are doing this:

```
SELECT sum(S.Sales),
       S.Sales
```

How do you envisage having both the SUM of Sales and the individual Sales in one and the same returned record? Since you group by Sales, SUM(Sales) is equal to Sales at any time, leading me to believe you are probably trying to accomplish something that is not refelcted in your query.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't mean to have the sum(S.Sales) in the first one. Thanks for pointing this out